# Binding View to ViewModel in xaml throws error "Cannot create an instance of"

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am new to the MVVM model, so I would like some advice.

Description:
Building a MVVM sample WPF application which reads the data from SQL table and displays them in a view. View uses WPFToolkit:grid to display the results. Application runs fine and able to show the result in grid. The application is developed using VS2010.

PeopleListView--> Display the results

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:PeopleViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<WpfToolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GetAllItems}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    Name="WpfGrid" Margin="0,0,28,0" Width="301">
    <WpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
        <WpfToolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Identifier" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
        <WpfToolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        <WpfToolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Create Date" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=CreateDate}"/>
    </WpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
</WpfToolkit:DataGrid>
```

PeopleViewModel-->

```
class PeopleViewModel
{
    PeopleRepository _Repository;

    public PeopleViewModel()
    {
        _Repository = new PeopleRepository();
    }

        public IEnumerable<Person> GetAllItems
        {
            get { return _Repository.GetAllItems(); }
        }
}
```

PeopleRepository--> Model class uses Entity Framework to get all the rows from DB.

```
class PeopleRepository 
{
    MyEntities _Context;

    public PeopleRepository()
    {
        _Context = new MyEntities();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Person> GetAllItems()
    {
        return _Context.People;
    }

}
```

MyEntities created using Entity Framework Model.

App.Config has the connection string created by the Entity Framework model.

In Vstudio design mode, the view user control throws error: ArgumentException was thrown on "PeopleViewModel": Cannot create an instance of "PeopleViewModel".

Error shown at line

```
    <vm:PeopleViewModel/>
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: But, is your code working fine at run-time?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your code is working fine at run-time. You can instruct the compiler to ignore some 'resource' specific operation while InDesignMode, and that would escape the exception you are getting.

Like:

```
if(! DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()) {
   //Use resources
}
```

Comment: Design view exception information shows as :The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid. Is it something related to Entity Creation in Repository? I dont understand why this error doesnt come when executing the app which shows all the rows in the grid!!

Comment: @ShyGuy: Because it doesn't exist when the code runs in the design surface.  This is the correct answer.

Comment: @Amby which Dependency are you suppose  to give it ?
if i wan't to place this check in the viewmodel constructor 
so i could reference it in xaml .

Comment: @eranotzer: Does not matter. You can create a new dependency object (as shown in example) and pass to the helper method. All it is doing is validating if the code is running in design mode or not, and that applies to any instance of Dependency Object.